# Cisco IOS privilege level explained

Tags: cisco, switch

I have access with level 1 privilege on a Cisco switch.  But, I want to see all configurations and interfaces, while being able to modify nothing. I searched the internet for the proper level of privilege but found nothing. Can someone explain each level and say which level is appropriate for seeing everything but modify nothing?

Comment: First hit in google for "cisco privilege level": http://www.techrepublic.com/article/understand-the-levels-of-privilege-in-the-cisco-ios/

Comment: Did you tried to search "privilege levels"?
Here's the first link from google search: http://tinyurl.com/p87829h. Or you did found something and it is still not clear?

Comment: yes, i read that before asking the question. I am still not clear. What does level 7,8,9,5,... have to offer?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you can create custom privilege levels for different users.

Comment: ok, so what level i must be to view everything on the switch bu not modify it?

Comment: Create a local user and set privilege level 2-14 with only one command "show run". In this case you will be able to view only running-config.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are 16 privilege levels. Usermode is level one. The highest is 15, sometimes referred to as privileged mode. There's also a level 0, which has even fewer options that usermode.

To get into level 15, where you can view configurations and modify them, type `enable` in usermode. Provided that you have the password, your prompt will change from `>` to `#`. You can then enter commands such as `show running-config`, `show startup-config`, `debug`, and `configure terminal`.

The other levels (2-14) are used for custom access. For instance, if I have a junior admin that I want to be able to have access to the command `show run`, but not `config t`, I can configure these specific rules to be associated with a particular level. Whatever level you are, you get access to everything in your level, plus all of the commands found with the lower levels.

For example:

```
username junioradmin privilege 2 password bingo
```

[This creates a login that when used will be placed in level 2 instead of the default level 1]

```
privilege exec level 2 show running-config
```

[This says to allow any level 2 user to have the ability to enter `show run`. But remember, they can also enter any command from a lower level, so all usermode commands are also included.]

```
line con 0
login local
```

[This will prompt for the username. It says to the device, "Use the local database for logging in."]

If you do this configuration, login, and then enter the `show run` command, it will work. Then enter `show start`; this will not work because `show start` is a level 15 command.